# i cannot able to pass data between viewcontrollers via protocols

Tags: swift

**View controller A**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: server?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.datum(data: "sd")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goingB", sender: self)
    }

}
```

**View controller B**

```
protocol server {
    func datum(data: String)
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, server {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }

    func datum(data: String) {
        self.label.text = data
        print(data)
    }

}
```

I need to pass the data via view controllers but I cannot able to pass however I know we can pass data through protocols, but anyhow I end up with error when try to run the program

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass data from one view controller to another and you're using segue for presenting new view controller, you can just override `prepare(for:sender:)`, there is no need to using delegates. Here you can get reference for controller which will be presented and you can assign its variable.

So, first create variable in second view controller and declare that if you assign it with new value, it changes text of your label

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var variable: String? {
        didSet {
            label.text = variable
        }
    }
}
```

Now in first view controller override `prepare(for:sender:)` and if segue is segue which you've performed, downcast destination view controller and assign its variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goingB", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goingB" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB
            destinationVC.variable = "sd"
        }
    }

}
```

---

Anyway, if you want to use your code with delegate, you have to set delegate of first view controller as second view controller which will be presented. For this purpose you can also use `prepare(for:sender:)` where you can get reference for destination of segue and then you can call your method on delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: server?

    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goingB", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goingB" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB
            delegate = destinationVC
            delegate?.datum(data: "sd")
        }
    }

}
```

---

Notes:

- Name protocol with big capital letter `Server` and we are talking about delegates, add delegate word: `ServerDelegate`
- Constrain protocol for just for classes
- Make then your delegate variable `weak`

---

```
protocol ServerDelegate: class {
    func datum(data: String)
}
```

...

```
weak var delegate: ServerDelegate?
```

Comment: my question is how to pass via protocols

Comment: @SubhashChandru but in this case there is no need to use protocols. Anyway, check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest here is to to set the property directly in prepare.

However, if you want to use delegate, you can. Your problem is that you have mixed between A and B.
The way you wrote it, when you call delegate?.datum, delegate is not defined and we can't access datum.
What do you want to do ? Go from A to B, and when in B, update a label in B with data received from A.
Here just to show how to use (but clearly too complex compared with direct assignment).

```
protocol Server {
    func datum() -> String
}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var delegate: Server?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let data = delegate?.datum()
        self.label.text = data
    }


}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, Server {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var data = "sd"

    func datum() -> String {
        return data
    }

    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goingB", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
            destVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```